# Update Django Object with Jquery, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to update a Django Object (`Company`) that already exists in the table by using jQuery.

The code I have executes fine, the Company object is not updated.

Here is an excerpt from my template:

```
{% if companies %}
        <tr class="gradeX">
            {% for company in companies %}
                <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ company.user.first_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ company.created_on }}</td>
                <td>Edit | Delete</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <strong>There are no companies yet.  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#addCompanyModal"> Do you want to create one?</a></strong>
    {% endif %}
```

The JavaScript I have tried is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function save_company()
    {
        $form=$('#addCompanyForm');
        var datastring = $form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: datastring,
            success: function(result)
            {
                $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-success"> <strong>Well done!</strong> New company added.</div>');
                $('#addCompanyModal').modal('hide');
                list_companies();
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert("failure:"+result.error);
                }
        });

        //don't submit the form

        return false;
    }

function list_companies()
    {

        $.get('/panel/company/list/json/', function(data) {
                $('#dynamic-table').html(data);
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Finally, here is the view I tried:

```
def list_companies_json(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        companies_list = Company.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-name')
        context_dict = {'companies': companies_list, 'form': form, 'errors': errors, 'success': success}
    #context_dict = serializers.serialize('json', list(companies_list))
    return render(request, 'panel/company/list_companies.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *certainly* possible and there are *many* ways to do this. Abstractly, all you need to do is pass the front-end some way to reference your object(s) so that jQuery (or whatever library/framework you want to use) can tell Django what object(s) needs updating. For the sake of clarity, I'll assume you want to update a *single* object -- but note that this same pipeline could scale to multiple objects just by using an `array` of identifiers/references instead of just one that we'll be using.

One way to do this is to pass the `id` of the Django object into the HTML (*disclaimer: there are more secure ways to do this, but for the sake of clear conceptualization it will suffice*). For example, to pass the `id` of each of your `company` objects, you could use:

```
{% for company in companies %}
  ...
<td class="companyID">{{ company.id }}</td>
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Say you wrapped each `company` in some wrapper, then you could just grab the `id` you want with a little jQuery:

```
var theCompany = ... // Maybe grabbed from a click? Really, it's up to you.
var theCompanyID = $(theCompany).find(".companyID").html();
```

Then, when you want to perform some "update" on that object, just include it in the `data` you send back to your view.

```
var data = {"theCompanyID":theCompanyID, ... }
$.post("/myURL/", data, someCallback);
```

After that, you can grab the corresponding Django object with `MyObject.get(id=theObjectID)` and update it however you need.

```
def myUpdateView(request):
  # We'll wrap the "update" portion in a Try-Except in case the user passes us
  # data that will break our update function. We should obviously check for
  # this BEFORE we attempt to perform the update -- but always best to be safe.
  try:
    theCompanyID = request.POST["theCompanyID"]
    theCompany = Company.objects.get(id=theCompanyID)

    # ... Now do the updates you want.

    theCompany.save()

    return HttpResponse("Update successful!")

  except:
    return HttpResponse("Oh... Update failed...")
```

Here's a [more in-depth tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/ajax.html) if you'd like to explore this more.

Comment: +1, I would just check for `request.method` before accessing the POST data.

Comment: Certainly! And also throw a try-except in the view in case the update fails for some reason. I was meaning to leave those details out since they can potentially be confusing, but it's probably a good idea to include them. Thanks, Karthikr!

Comment: thanks, but I think that works for update a single record, what I'm trying to do is "refresh"the whole list to get the new result just added, in fact I want to update the whole list (companies), but thanks again I will use that for the single record update

Comment: Your question asks for a **single** "Django *object*" -- **not to bulk update many Django objects**. Besides, the same pipeline works; just pass multiple IDs instead of the one and use a loop. The code is meant to be a guideline; if you just copy-paste, you won't learn anything. ;)

Comment: sorry mate for the confusion, I think I wasn't clear, I don't want to update a bulk, I've a list (companies) who I loop through printing to the table, at the same page I have a form to create a new company, I just want to "refresh" the list after create a new company ... so the list will have this new record after it render again ... when I said update I messed it up, is just a list refresh with the new record, but thanks a lot again I will try something based on what you post too already clarified some points in my mind, thanks again

Comment: Ahh, I see. That is NOT the question you asked. Please be more clear next time. What you want is just to reload part of your big template, yes? What you should do is abstract the `table` HTML into another template and have a view that simply renders it by itself; then, you can use a `$.get("/myRefreshedTableURL/", ... )` and just `replace` the current `table` element with the response you get. Make sense?

Comment: Yes thats what I'm trying to do, the table is already in other template which I include on my main template, but nothing is reload..., just when I force refresh in browser the data appear, but with the $.get no... thanks again!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57421/discussion-between-casey-falk-and-tubadc).